# Credential Manager Wildcard Credential with DNS Suffix in Adapter Setting

Tags: windows, credentials-manager

I have a credential stored in the credential manager for a wildcard domain (*.example.com). I've also added example.com to the IPV4 and IPV6 Advanced TCP/IP settings to automatically append that suffix. Trouble is, when I try to access a file share like `\\something`, rather than `\\something.example.com`, I'm still prompted for my credentials. It seems that even though challenge-response is still happening, but that Windows isn't checking my credential store for those creds. Any thoughts or ways to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean \\something?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 yes, I did, and that's how it was typed, though the formatting was escaping something. Fixed it though, thanks!

Comment: Super late to the party here.. Did you ever find a work around for this? I am having the same issue between 2 domains. Wildcard works if I fully qualify my server name, otherwise I have to add credentials for each individual server I am connecting to

Comment: @Curtis, I don't remember finding a good solution other than to fully qualify the domain.

Comment: I think the problem is a check that the “Common Name” of the certificate matches the FQDN. In that case there's no solution that uses wildcards.

Comment: This isn't about certificates at all though?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem with Windows, perhaps related to the way that
the certificate is checked. There is no information coming from
Microsoft, but it is thought that Windows checks that the "Common Name"
of the certificate matches the
[Fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

If this assumption is correct, there's no solution that uses wildcards,
except for fully qualifying the server-name.

Comment: Ouch.  I have a DFS share that is served by ~30 Windows Servers.  A credential manager entry for 'cust.local' means I can access everything (i.e. \\server1.cust.local and \\server2.cust.local)...but DFS doesn't work even though the namespace servers are referenced by FQDN.  Anyways, adding the FQDN of every single server in to credential manager makes it start working again.  Absolutely lame, Microsoft.